# How can I add files to the bootclasspath in maven correctly?

Tags: java, maven-2, pom.xml, jsr166

I'm using some [JSR166](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/) classes with Java 1.6, some of which are under `java.util.concurrent`. I am on OSX, though I expect this to ultimately run on Linux.

If I set this environment variable I can run my project:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xbootclasspath/p:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jsr166-mirror/jsr166/1.7.0/jsr166-1.7.0.jar
```

I tried following the instructions [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html) and putting the setting in my `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <version>3.0</version>
      <compilerArguments>
        <verbose/>
        <bootclasspath>/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jsr166-mirror/jsr166/1.7.0/jsr166-1.7.0.jar</bootclasspath>
      </compilerArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Unfortunately this gave an error about not being able to find `java.lang`. If I add a reference to `classes.jar` (apparently OSX's version of `rt.jar`) in the `bootclasspath` I can fix that error, but that just puts me back where I started:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.util.concurrent
```

**How should I set up maven to use this argument correctly?**

Answer (score 0):

You should check security manager. Unfortunately, I don't know specific on OSX. By default, the JVMuses security policies defined in the java.security and java.policy files located under the JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security folder. Check also -Djava.security.manager and –Djava.security.policy option for your JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use extdir for this, instead of bootclasspath?

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-verbose</arg>
            <arg>-extdir /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jsr166-mirror/jsr166/1.7.0/</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

From http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html